# Convert list of lists to unique dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have the following list of lists: `[[100, 23], [101, 34], [102, 35] ... ]`

How can i convert it to a dictionary like that: `{100: 23, 101: 34, 102: 35 ... }`

Here is what i tried:

```
myDict = dict(map(reversed, myList))
```

This code works, but it will give the opposite of what i want in the dictionary: `{23: 100, 101:34..}`

Comment: Just `dict(myList)`…!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a list with this format to `dict()` and it will convert it for you.

```
myList = [[100, 23], [101, 34], [102, 35]]

myDict = dict(myList)

print(myDict)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to docs page for [dict()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict)

> . . . the positional argument must be an iterable object. Each item in the iterable must itself be an iterable with exactly two objects. The first object of each item becomes a key in the new dictionary, and the second object the corresponding value.

and here is an example for the same doc page:

```
...
>>> d = dict([('two', 2), ('one', 1), ('three', 3)])
```

returns a dictionary equal to `{"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}`

Answer (score -1):

```
L = []
A = {}
for x,y in L:
    A[x] = y
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.